# Network only showing the current computer, but not all the other computers connected to the Workgroup

Tags: windows-7, networking

We actually have a `WD MyCloud` that networks all our computers and it was working fine until the internet router and internet provider was changed. Only 1 computer was not able to see the other computers in the network after the change. The other computers are connected fine.

The computer is on `Windows 7`

I have checked `services.msc` and tried all settings for `Computer Browser` (manual and automatic) and both does nothing.

I have also checked all the networking options in the control panel and they are all allowed (Enable file sharing, printers, and etc. on a Private network)

I have also checked the Workgroup to ensure that they are on the same workgroup. The default name and the joined workgroup of the computers as well as noted on the configuration of the `WD MyCloud` is "Workgroup" which is also the workgroup of the computer not showing.

The thing I noticed about the problematic computer is that when pointing to the internet, it will display the  list of wireless networks (e.g. OurWifi) as shown below:

[image]

While the computers with no problems are connected to the internet as well, but shows a computer icon indicating it is connected to a network instead of the bars that signifies wifi:

[image]

Comment: You said you made sure the firewall permissions are 'allow' on a private network, but are you actually set to a private network? Open the network and sharing center, under the name of your network there is a link "Home Network" or "Work Network". As a sanity check, if you know the MyCloud's IP, you can open Windows Explorer and type "\\<IP-of-MyCloud>" (e.g. `\\192.168.0.4`) into the address bar. This does not rely on discovery.

Comment: @Andy I'm sorry I missed that detail, but it was initially a "Home Network" then I changed it to "Work Network" thinking there might be a difference, but there is no difference. I believe I tried typing the IP I found in the network options, but it returned a page that cannot be loaded. I'll check again

Comment: @Andy right so I tried typing that IP address into the address bar for the computers that work, and they connect to the WdMyCloud's interface, but when I do it on the affected computer, the page just times out

Comment: I updated my main post about something I noticed and may be very related to the issue.

Comment: Is your wifi the same network as your wired network?

Comment: @Andy not sure how to check that but we only have 1 internet

Comment: What are the IP addresses of the three machines? The MyCloud, the problem computer, and the working computer? If you google "what is my IP" from each machine, do you get the same result?

Comment: @Andy The default gateway and subnet mask is the same for all computers, but the IPv4 is different per computer. These are from 2 working and connected to the WDMyCloud with no issues and the problematic one. The WdMyCloud has a different IP from the default gateway and the IPv4 from all the computers.